# Which repository format shall I use with Sonatype Nexus for ungeneric build outputs?

Tags: nexus, build-process, sonatype, ddd-repositories, build-pipeline

**Use case**

I have a C++ build pipeline that creates my application. The output of this pipeline is a directory which contains my C++ application. I didn't know where to put them, so I installed `Sonatype Nexus` in order to categorize, and manage these build outputs. (Just to clarify what my initial requirement is)

**After installation**

After installing [Sonatype Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/product-nexus-repository) I can now configure my build artifact repository. In the configuration I have the choice to use a repository format, but none of the ones listed seems to fit my requirement. I can only find repository formats which seem to be used as an **input** for my pipeline, but not as an **output**. Is there anything I miss or which format would fit my need?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `raw` format will allow you to store any arbitrary file type in any arbitrary folder structure.

That being said, I'm not at all a C/C++ expert, but the [`Conan` format](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages.html) seems to be dedicated to packaging for your language.

I see a little star next to the format name in your screenshot indicating that this was still a community supported plugin. Hence you are running a nexus version older than 3.22.0.

You should consider upgrading since the `conan` format is now part of the core nexus and that your version is subject to security vulnerabilities that were fixed in 3.22.0 and 3.22.1. See [release notes](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/release-notes/2020-release-notes)